# How to create NSMutableArray by plist file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, plist

Previously, I used the following code to create an array for me and it worked.

```
bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
path = [bundle pathForResource:@"MultiSetting" ofType:@"plist"];    
settingArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

But after that, I wanted to modify the plist file, therefore, I used the following code to do that and it's NOT working.

```
NSFileManager *mgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *documentPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentDirectory = [documentPath objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *dstPath = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MultiSetting.plist"];

bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *srcPath = [bundle pathForResource:@"MultiSetting" ofType:@"plist"];
NSError *error = nil;
[mgr copyItemAtPath:srcPath toPath:dstPath error:(NSError **)error];

settingArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:dstPath];
NSLog(@"%@", settingArray);
```

Is there any solution to solve this problem? Did I do anything wrong?

Comment: It is not work......
I change the code: http://i.imgur.com/bcgp0iV.png

But the settingArray still being null.

Comment: Show the structure of plist with same sample data...

Comment: the previous image, the typo is template.plist should be changed to MultiSetting.plist

The structure of plist: http://i.imgur.com/4xLVXyS.png
But something strange is if I change the settingArray initwithcontensfile of srcPath, the array can be shown. If the settingArray initwithcontentsfile of dstPath, the array cannot be shown.

Is the copying process wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you are passing `error` wrong. You need to change that line to

```
[mgr copyItemAtPath:srcPath toPath:dstPath error:&error];
```

Another thing according to your code after the first run, the above line will fail as there will already be a file that particular name. If you want to initialize only once then I guess you could write something like below which makes more sense:

```
NSError *error = nil;
if (![mgr fileExistsAtPath:dstPath]) {
    [mgr copyItemAtPath:srcPath toPath:dstPath error:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```

And finally `initWithContentsOfFile:` might be failing because the plist cannot be parsed into an array. This can be because your plist file's root object is a dictionary (the default when you create the plist using Xcode).

Since you are able to parse the plist file in bundle it might be because, you might have accidentally copied the wrong file (or an empty file or a plist with root as dictionary) the first time and then was not able to copy. So try deleting the file from `dstPath` and try again.

To check the file do an `NSLog` of `dstPath`. For example if you get something like this in the console:

```
/Users/xxxx/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/194351E6-C64E-4CE6-8C82-8F66C8BFFAAF/Documents/YourAppName.app
```

Copy this till the Documents folder, i.e

```
/Users/xxxx/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/194351E6-C64E-4CE6-8C82-8F66C8BFFAAF/Documents/
```

Go to:

> Finder -> Go -> Go To Folder

and paste the path and click on `Go`. This should take you to the actual directory and check the contents of the plist . Open it as source code in Xcode to see what is the root object.

Also try deleting this file you find here and running your app agin.

Another way to achieve the above would be to initialize the array from bundle and then write it directly instead of copying the file (but this is not a the direct answer to your problem just a workaround) i.e :

```
NSString *srcPath = [bundle pathForResource:@"MultiSetting" ofType:@"plist"];
NSError *error = nil;
//initialize from source
NSMutableArray *settingsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:srcPath];
//write to file
NSError *error = nil;
//check if file exists
if (![mgr fileExistsAtPath:dstPath]) {
    [settingArray writeToFile:dstPath atomically: YES];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```

Comment: The strange thing is my code now is settingArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:dstPath];, the array cannot be shown.

If I change it to settingArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:srcPath];, the array can be shown.

Comment: This might be because you might be having two different files at the paths. The file you copied the first time might be different (after you changed the plist maybe?). I'll edit the answer to check the file.

Comment: I got the answer. But there is a further problem is that the code above is in view2, i want to change some values of plist in view 2, and then the user go back view 1, some things will be updated. But I find that everytime I go to view 2 from view 1. The array will be initiated. Is there any way to save the things in my document directory permanently?

Comment: Sure. Thats what the second part of my answer does. It checks if file is present and writes only if you want. If you don't want to reinitialize the values, then don't do the copy if file exists. Moreover if its getting reinitialized each time when you don't want it to then the place you are writing the code is probably wrong. Where are you writing this code? I'll updated the answer to initialize only once.

Comment: Do u have skype account, so that I can send my file to u as the code is long to copy to this. Thanks!

Comment: I don't have Skype access right now. But what you are trying to accomplish wouldn't be too complicated.

Comment: I dont have enough reputation, so that I cannot enter the chat :(

Comment: give me a minute, i'll see if I can log into Skype.

Comment: Np.Whats your Skype name?

Comment: My skype id: cheong0130

Answer (score 0):

Any changes you make to the `settingArray` array do not automatically get saved to disk. You need to explicitly save it to disk. When you actually want to save the contents of the `settingArray` variable, you need to call:

```
[settingArray writeToFile:dstPath atomically: YES];
```

Comment: I know that. But actually, even I use NSLog the settingArray after I initwithContentsOfFile, thats result null.